# ROC-Curve calculation of elements

Tags: machine-learning, roc, confusion-matrix

I know that the ROC-Curve is calculated from the True-Positive-Rate and the False-Positive-Rate.

But the ROC-Curve has infinite Elements on it's Curve, right? How is each Element calculated? Can someone explain this to me? Where is each point coming from?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TekPf.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's the difference between the theoretical binormal ROC curve and the empirical one. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/105501/36682 for  a description the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are calculated for all values of the threshold of the classifier.

On the x axis, you have the "false positive rate" for the given threshold: FPR = FP / (TN + FP) where:

- FP are the number of false positive (the elements predicted positive but which are negative);
- TN the number of true negative (the elements predicted negative and are really negative);
- and FP the number of false positive (the elements predicted positive but are negative).

On the y axis, you have the "true positive rate" for the given threshold: TPR = TP / (TP + FN) where:

- TP are the number of true positive (predicted positive and are indeed positive);
- FN the number of false negative (predicted negative but are positive).

You have not an infinite number of points in practice: you are limited to the number of points of the dataset (the rate dont change for some ranges of threshold).